# Copy Range from Worksheets to Master Worksheet where data is visualized

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a certain range of data from all worksheets that don't have the name "Pivot_Time" or "Pivot_Expenses" or "Pull & Copy Data" and paste it into the current worksheet.

So far my code does what I want but since I want to visualize the data with a pivot chart the pasted data has to be formatted as a table. Unfortunately my code doesn't do that. Any ideas on how I can do that?

Thanks in advance!

This is the code I've tried:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRangeToPivotTable_Pivot_Time()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Pivot_Time" And ws.Name <> "Pivot_Expenses" _
        And ws.Name <> "Pull & Copy Data" Then
            ws.Range("A14:L26").Copy
            Sheets("Pivot_Time").Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset (1)
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunatly the code still does the same. I need it to be formatted as a table in order to visualize it with a pivot chart. I created the columns for the table already but the data is filled in below the table as I think VBA doesn't recognize the empty cells of the table as empty.

Comment: I do not see the code for paste. Also not sure in which sheet you want to paste the rows.

Comment: Hi Anna. Edits on questions don't provide answers. I edited this to make the code more readable for the community.

Comment: @RyanWildry oh my bad, didn't know that

Comment: @J.B.      ws.Range("A14:L26").Copy
            Sheets("Pivot_Time").Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset (1)         This part copies and pastes the Range. The Range should be pasted in the worksheet "Pivot_Time"

Comment: So far the code does what it should. My problem is just that the pasted cells are not formatted as tables and therefore can't be automatically visualized with a Pivotchart. What I want the code to do is add the cells to the table I created

Comment: As per my understanding the values pasted are going to be part of one big table, right?

Comment: @Ricardo Diaz excactly! The values should be added to the already existing table.

Comment: And the existing table is an structured Excel table? If it is, it isn’t auto-expanding? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

Comment: yes it is a structured Excel table. And the data is pasted below the last cell of the table instead of in the table. I think VBA doesn't recognize the cells of the table as empty cells and therefore pastes the data below, where they are not formatted as tables

Comment: I have structured the head of the table in Range (K1:V1) but as I said the data is not pasted in the table

Comment: Any ideas on how to change that would be great! Or how the imported cells can be automatically moved upwards to the range (K2:W2) , so they will be pasted over what VBA thinks are nonempty cells.

Comment: Check the answer I provided and let me know if it helps. I refactored the code so it's easier to customize to fit your needs and prevents possible errors..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but still you can refresh the existing pivot table with new range by using following code:

```
   'Refresh Pivot table
    LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    NewRange = "Pivot_Time!A1:AL" & LastRow 'Set Range as per your requirement
    Sheets("Pivot Sheet").Select 'Set the sheet name where your pivot table is saved
    Sheets("Pivot Sheet").PivotTables("pivot table name").ChangePivotCache ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pivot Sheet").PivotTables("pivot table name").RefreshTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in a module and adapt the <<<< customize this >>>> section

```
Sub CopyRangeToPivotTable_Pivot_Time()

    ' Declare objects variables
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destinationTable As ListObject

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim destinationSheetName As String
    Dim destinationTableName As String
    Dim sourceRangeAddress As String
    Dim specialSheetsList() As Variant

    ' <<<< Customize this >>>>
    destinationSheetName = "Pivot_Time"
    destinationTableName = "Table1"
    sourceRangeAddress = "A14:L26"
    specialSheetsList = Array("Pivot_Time", "Pivot_Expenses", "Pull & Copy Data")

    ' Initialize destination table
    Set destinationTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(destinationSheetName).ListObjects(destinationTableName)

    ' When using screenupdating you better add an error handler, cause you might end up with the screen not updating, restarting excel if the procedure fails, and possibly loosing data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each sourceSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' if the macro is going to run in other workbooks, return to activeworkbook

        If IsInArray(sourceSheet.Name, specialSheetsList) = False Then


            ' Copy the range - no clipboard
            destinationTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(destinationTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Range(sourceRangeAddress).Rows.Count, Range(sourceRangeAddress).Columns.Count).Value = sourceSheet.Range(sourceRangeAddress).Value

            ' Resize the table to include the new data
            destinationTable.Resize destinationTable.Range.CurrentRegion


        End If

    Next sourceSheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

' Credits: https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/check-if-value-is-in-array-vba/
Private Function IsInArray(valToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
'DEVELOPER: Ryan Wells (wellsr.com)
'DESCRIPTION: Function to check if a value is in an array of values
'INPUT: Pass the function a value to search for and an array of values of any data type.
'OUTPUT: True if is in array, false otherwise
Dim element As Variant
On Error GoTo IsInArrayError: 'array is empty
    For Each element In arr
        If element = valToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next element
Exit Function
IsInArrayError:
On Error GoTo 0
IsInArray = False
End Function
```